# Does Go or Beego supports dynamic url routing like id=?

Tags: url, go, router, beego, dynamic-url

```
func main() {

    beego.Router("/", &MainController{})
    beego.Router("/userid/", &SqlController{})
    beego.Run()

}
```

this works fine for url "http://localhost:8080/userid"
but if i want user id value to be dynamic for ex "http://localhost:8080?userid=1"
i could not how o achieve this using router in go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting `xxx` from `?id=xxx` is about request parameter parsing, you can get examples in [beego's document](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/params.md).

Routing (in your context) is about mapping requests matching a certain pattern to corresponding actions. When id is different, I suppose what you want is not getting them mapped to different actions. So it shouldn't be called routing. It's just parameter parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about beego, but using go http request you can access the query parameters like this 
`request.URL.Query()`, where `request` is of type `*http.Request`. What you want is basically query parameters from the URL? So you get the URL object from the the request and then access the query parameters. The `Query()` method returns a `map[string][]string`

Comment: nope this i have tried...will produce segmentation violation panic

Comment: I use gorilla mux and golang http package and it works well for me.